# Write to every files in a directory with loop

Tags: python, for-loop

With the code below I have made a htmlfiles.txt that contains HTML filenames in a directory:

```
import os
entries = os.listdir('/home/stupidroot/Documents/html.files.test')
count=0
for line in entries:
    count += 1
    f = open("htmlfiles.txt", "a")
    f.write(line + "\n")
    f.close()
```

In the second phase I want to make modification in every file like this:

```
lines = open('filename.html').readlines()
open('filename.html', 'w').writelines(lines[20:-20])
```

This code deletes the first and the last 20 lines in a HTML file.

I just want to make with all files with for loop simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to open the `htmlfiles.txt` file, and read each filename from each line and do your stuff :

```
with open("htmlfiles.txt") as fic:
    for filename in fic:
        filename = filename.rstrip()
        lines = open(filename).readlines()
        open(filename, 'w').writelines(lines[20:-20])
```